# Incrementing ISODate by x days inside aggregrations

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to increment an ISODate by one day inside a more complex mongodb aggregation (not shown here).  Here I tried to setup a dumbed-down example inside the mongo shell:

```
rs:PRIMARY> dts=new Date("2007-08-06T15:01:00Z")
ISODate("2007-08-06T15:01:00Z")
rs:PRIMARY> new Date({ 
...        $add: [{
...           "$subtract": [
...              "$dts", 
...              new Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
...           ]}, 
...           1000*60*60*24,
...        ]}
...     )
ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ")
```

Here I take the input Date/Timestamp (labeled 'dts') and subtract it from the Epoch (1970-01-01).  I verified this result gives the the number of milliseconds since the Epoch (not shown here).

Then I'm taking 1 day converted into milliseconds (1000ms * 60s * 60min * 24 hrs) and add it to the results of the subtraction operation.  This should yield a long integer value for number of milliseconds since Epoch for this Date/Timestamp: "2007-08-07T15:01:00Z".  So the result should be exactly one day increment from the input dts value.

Through some experimentation, I found that the problem probably lies somewhere in the fact that I'm providing addition results to new Date().  But then how would you go about generating an ISODate that is incremented by one day here?

---

### FOLLOW ON COMMENT

Okay I realize that I could do just this inside a mongo shell to get what I want:

```
rs:PRIMARY> new Date((dts - new Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z") + 1000*60*60*24))
ISODate("2007-08-07T15:01:00Z")
```

But I'm trying to put this into a much more complex aggregation expression, and I believe you cannot just use the JavaScript syntax as I've done here inside aggregation expressions.  So I'm really trying to figure out how to make this work with expressions using $subtract and $add.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to demonstrate this inside the Mongo shell, but one solution is to use $toDate (new in v4.0).

```
{$toDate: {
   $add: [{
      "$subtract": [
         dts, 
         new Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
      ]}, 
      1000*60*60*24,
   ]
}}
```

See $toDate doc:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/

This approach will work inside an aggregation as desired.